# Can't connect to WCF service on Android

Tags: android, wcf, soap

I am trying to connect to a .NET WCF service in Android using kSOAP2 (v 2.1.2), but I keep getting a fatal exception whenever I try to make the service call. I'm having a bit of difficulty tracking down the error and can't seem to figure out why it's happening. The code I am using is below:

```
package org.example.android;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransport;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ValidateUser extends Activity {
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/mobile/ValidateUser";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "ValidateUser";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/mobile/";    
    private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.2:8002/WebService.Mobile.svc"; 

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */  
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.validate_user);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if (extras == null) {
            this.finish();
        }
        String username = extras.getString("username");
        String password = extras.getString("password");                               

        Boolean validUser = false;


        try {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            PropertyInfo uName = new PropertyInfo();
            uName.name = "userName";

            PropertyInfo pWord = new PropertyInfo();
            pWord.name = "passWord";

            request.addProperty(uName, username);
            request.addProperty(pWord, password);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransport(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); // error occurs here

            Integer userId = (Integer)envelope.getResponse();
            validUser = (userId != 0);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }               
    }

    private void exit () {
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Remove the old stack traces. In summary, the first problem was the program being unable to open a connection due to missing methods or libraries due to using vanilla kSOAP2 rather than a modified library for Android (kSOAP2-Android). The second issue was a settings issue. In the Manifest I did not add the following setting:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I am now having an issue with the XMLPullParser which I need to figure out.

> 12-23 10:58:06.480:
>   ERROR/SOCKETLOG(210): add_recv_stats
>   recv 0
>
> 12-23 10:58:06.710:
>   WARN/System.err(210):
>   org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException:
>   unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT
>   null@1:0 in
>   java.io.InputStreamReader@433fb070)
>
> 12-23 10:58:06.710:
>   WARN/System.err(210):     at
>   org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.exception(KXmlParser.java:243)
>
> 12-23 10:58:06.720:
>   WARN/System.err(210):     at
>   org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextTag(KXmlParser.java:1363)
>
> 12-23 10:58:06.720:
>   WARN/System.err(210):     at
>   org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:126)
>
> 12-23 10:58:06.720:
>   WARN/System.err(210):     at
>   org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:63)
>
> 12-23 10:58:06.720:
>   WARN/System.err(210):     at
>   org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:100)
>
> 12-23 10:58:06.730:
>   WARN/System.err(210):     at
>   org.example.android.ValidateUser.onCreate(ValidateUser.java:68)
>
> 12-23 10:58:06.730:
>   WARN/System.err(210):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1122)
>
> 12-23 10:58:06.730:
>   WARN/System.err(210):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
>
> 12-23 10:58:06.730:
>   WARN/System.err(210):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2157)
>
> 12-23 10:58:06.730:
>   WARN/System.err(210):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)
>
> 12-23 10:58:06.730:
>   WARN/System.err(210):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1581)
>
> 12-23 10:58:06.730:
>   WARN/System.err(210):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:88)
>
> 12-23 10:58:06.730:
>   WARN/System.err(210):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>
> 12-23 10:58:06.730:
>   WARN/System.err(210):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3739)
>
> 12-23 10:58:06.730:
>   WARN/System.err(210):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method)
>
> 12-23 10:58:06.730:
>   WARN/System.err(210):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>
> 12-23 10:58:06.730:
>   WARN/System.err(210):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
>
> 12-23 10:58:06.730:
>   WARN/System.err(210):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:497)
>
> 12-23 10:58:06.730:
>   WARN/System.err(210):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
>   Method)

Comment: Not sure about the first log, but in the second log the 'unknown error' is from a unhandled SOCKERR_ in the native code. There should be a logcat entry just above starting 'unknown socket error ' what is that line?

Comment: I edited the logs to show the 5 lines above the exception.

Comment: I was able to resolve the unknown socket exception. It seems I neglected (and was rather ignorant of) a setting I had to add to my Manifest file. That being: 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />. Now I have an XMLPullParserException that I need to figure out.

Comment: It seems there is a bug in kSOAP2-Android. It is using an Envelope NS which is incompatible with, at least, WCF and is not pre-pending "urn:" to the NS of method names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working. There were some issues as mentioned above with the Manifest file. On top of that the NAMESPACE, SOAP_ACTION, and URL parameters were incorrect. The NAMESPACE required "uri:" to be pre-pended to it, as did SOAP_ACTION. The URL needed to have an endpoint specified so instead of http://192.168.1.2:8002/WebService.Mobile.svc it needed to be http://192.168.1.2:8002/WebService.Mobile.svc/Mobile. Connection issues resolved, just need to figure out the data transport thing now.

Comment: You mentioned that you had to add 'uri:' to the namespace. So did your final namespace look like:

private static final String NAMESPACE = "uri://tempuri.org/mobile/";

Would you be able to post your final code?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and found this: http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/issues/detail?id=35

See Comments 15 and 17.

They suggest that you wrap the call to "androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);"
in try/catch and try again in case of an error.

OR

Set the system property "http.keepAlive" to "false".

Later on in that issue someone suggests usage of "KeepAliveHttsTransport".

For me, the (I admit it's dirty) try/catch worked just fine.

EDIT typo