# Consume ado.net data service from android 2.1

Tags: java, android, json, wcf-data-services, restlet

I have a ado.net data service created using VS 2008 sp 1 that is hosted that I want to consume via HTTP and JSON from Android 2.1? Does anyone have sample code on how to do CRUD operations easily do this? I heard Restlet makes this very easy but can't seem to find sample Android code on doing this. If someone can post a tutorial with some actual code that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

here is a good link..

http://composedcrap.blogspot.com/2009/08/connecting-to-net-web-service-from.html

It uses `ksoap2 API`

http://www.tuxpan.com/android-soap/android-ksoap2-build.zip

another link from right here on SO...

[How to call a .NET Webservice from Android using KSOAP2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052300/how-to-call-a-net-webservice-from-android-using-ksoap2)

And here is a link for Android to WCF....

[Can't connect to WCF service on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949814/cant-connect-to-wcf-service-on-android)

For a RESTful WCF service, here is a good tutorial...

http://mypetprojects.blogspot.com/2009/05/communication-between-wcf-service-and.html

Comment: These samples show examples with SOAP web service. Do you know any links for consuming RESTful ADO.net Data services using the JSON protocol?

Comment: Added another link to the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 1):

I found another link: http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/28-restlet/287-restlet/288-restlet.html

Seems usefull.

(+1 for Eclipsed4utoo for all the links!)

Answer (score 0):

Reached here late(or very late) but may help someone in present or future. If you are looking to consume a ado.net data service(now renamed WCF Data Service) from android client, I would recommend you to have a look at the [OData4j](http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/) library. It provides an easy way to access such a service in both xml and json format. Also, it is faster than RESTlet.
Sample code:

```
ODataConsumer c = ODataJerseyConsumer.create("http://url/WebService.svc");

List<OEntity> listEntities = c.getEntities("Movies").execute().toList();

if (listEntities.size() > 0 ) {

for(OEntity entity : listEntities) {

System.out.println(entity.getProperty("MovieID").getValue().toString());
   }
}
```

You can find more on WCF Data Service and OData4j [here](http://www.loginworks.com/technical-blogs/266-consuming-wcf-data-serviceodata-in-androidjava).